# Working on discord.js v14.9.0, an error TypeError: MessageActionRow is not a constructor keeps apearing

Tags: javascript, constructor, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot using discord.js v14.9.0. Actually, Im working on a combat command.

This is my code:

````
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButtonComponent, Discord } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('combate')
        .setDescription('Empieza un combate contra un slime.'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        // Variables del usuario
        let usuario_vida = 100;
        let usuario_ataque = 0;

        // Variables del slime
        let slime_vida = 50;
        let slime_ataque = 0;

        // Función para lanzar el dado
        function rollDice(dado) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * dado) + 1;
        }

        // Función para mostrar el resultado del combate
        function mostrarResultado(ataque, defensa, ataque_roll, defensa_roll) {
            let resultado = "";
            resultado += `El ${ataque} ha atacado y ha hecho ${ataque_roll} puntos de daño.\n`;
            resultado += `La ${defensa} ha recibido ${ataque_roll} puntos de daño y ahora tiene ${defensa_roll} puntos de vida.`;
            return resultado;
        }



            function mostrarTablaVidas(vida_usuario, vida_slime) {
            let tabla = "```";
            tabla += `Slime: ${vida_slime} puntos de vida\n`;
            tabla += "- - -\n- - -\n- - -\n- - -\n- - -\n";
            tabla += `Usuario: ${vida_usuario} puntos de vida\n` + "```";
            return tabla;
        }

        // Función para actualizar la tabla de vidas
        async function actualizarTablaVidas(interaction, vida_usuario, vida_slime) {
            const tabla = mostrarTablaVidas(vida_usuario, vida_slime);
            const row = new MessageActionRow()
                .addComponents(
                    new MessageButtonComponent()
                        .setCustomId('ataque')
                        .setLabel('Atacar')
                        .setColor('PRIMARY')
                );
            await interaction.editReply({ content: tabla, components: [row] });
        }

        // Mostrar la tabla de vidas y el botón de ataque
        await actualizarTablaVidas(interaction, usuario_vida, slime_vida);

        // Registrar la función que se llamará cuando se haga clic en el botón de ataque
        const filter = i => i.customId === 'ataque' && i.user.id === interaction.user.id;
        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });
        collector.on('interactionCreate', async (buttonInteraction) => {
            if (buttonInteraction.isButton() && buttonInteraction.customId === 'ataque') {
                // El usuario ataca al slime
                const ataque_roll = rollDice(6);
                slime_vida -= ataque_roll;
                const resultado_usuario = mostrarResultado("usuario", "slime", ataque_roll, slime_vida);

                            // El slime ataca al usuario
            const defensa_roll = rollDice(4);
            usuario_vida -= defensa_roll;
            const resultado_slime = mostrarResultado("slime", "usuario", defensa_roll, usuario_vida);

            // Actualizar la tabla de vidas
            await actualizarTablaVidas(buttonInteraction, usuario_vida, slime_vida);

            // Mostrar el resultado del ataque
            await buttonInteraction.followUp({ content: resultado_usuario + "\n" + resultado_slime });

            // Comprobar si el combate ha terminado
            if (usuario_vida <= 0) {
                await buttonInteraction.followUp({ content: "Has perdido el combate." });
                collector.stop();
            } else if (slime_vida <= 0) {
                await buttonInteraction.followUp({ content: "Has ganado el combate." });
                collector.stop();
            }
        }
    });

    // Tiempo máximo de espera para el botón de ataque
    collector.on('end', async () => {
        await interaction.editReply({ content: "El combate ha terminado." });
    });
},
};
````

And this is the error that keeps appearing in the console everythime I try to use de command:

TypeError: MessageActionRow is not a constructor
at actualizarTablaVidas (C:\Users\usago\OneDrive\Escritorio\RpgBot\commands\combate.js:43:25)
at Object.execute (C:\Users\usago\OneDrive\Escritorio\RpgBot\commands\combate.js:54:15)
at Client. (C:\Users\usago\OneDrive\Escritorio\RpgBot\index.js:33:17)
at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\usago\OneDrive\Escritorio\RpgBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\usago\OneDrive\Escritorio\RpgBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\usago\OneDrive\Escritorio\RpgBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\usago\OneDrive\Escritorio\RpgBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:494:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\usago\OneDrive\Escritorio\RpgBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:328:10)
at callListener (C:\Users\usago\OneDrive\Escritorio\RpgBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14)

No matter what I change, everytame it ends whit this error apearing in the console.

What is suposed to hapen when I use the command is that the table appears WITH the buttons for the user to atack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no longer use `MessageActionRow` or `MessageButtonComponent` in Discord.js. Replace them with `ActionRowBuilder` and `ButtonBuilder`.